# Android activity black start screen with PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, screen, init

I've a little issues with android and phonegap build. 
It is not appearing when compiling directly from eclipse.

When I submit my files to PGB and download the compiled app, I start the app. 
Now for a second there appears an empty native android activity with the name of my app on the top line. Then my app view starts.

This is annoying. 
How can I prevent that?

Comment: I too have the same issue in my emulator 
someone help soon please

Comment: @Robin - Why don't you try this alternative from Cordova 1.9+ [CorovaWebView](https://github.com/Linnesq/EmbeddedCorovaWebViewDemo)

Comment: @Hari - Please read through you may find this useful [WebView](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android)

Answer (score 0):

You can't completely prevent it.
The first blank/black screen that appear before any splashscreen of your app is normal.

That black screen is a sort of Android internal base screen that Android shows for your app while it fork a process in the Dalvik JVM and load your resources/classes. it happen for any Android app. it is not related to Phonegap. Android make this to give the user the impression of a "fast app launch" while it instead is still loading your code.

Anyway you can style that black screen to make it appear as near as possible to the theme of your app so the user have the impression the app is ready and launched but it is loading internal content.

You can read more about it here: http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/